# AngularJS ngShow and focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Attempting to show a `textarea` in Angular based on whether or not a `preview` variable is true. After `preview` is set to true I'd like to set focus to the `textarea` as well.

**Controller Logic**

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.preview = false;
    $scope.showPreview = function() {
        $scope.preview = true;
    }
}])
```

**Directive Logic**

```
.directive('previewFocus', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.$watch('preview', 
         function (newValue) { 
            newValue && element[0].focus();
         },true);
      };    
});
```

Then I have a `div` that when clicked, it will fire off the `showPreview()` method:

```
<div ng-click="showPreview()">Add Post</div>
```

And a `textarea` with the `preview-focus` directive:

```
<textarea class="previewInput" preview-focus></textarea>
```

I've debugged the code and everything executes as expected, including the callback on the `scope.$watch` function. However, the `textarea` does not take focus. If I don't use the `ngShow` directive, the focus works fine. Below are two JSFiddle examples to show both cases.

**Focus does not work**: [JSFiddle with ngShow](http://jsfiddle.net/Dm5LG/1/)

**Focus works fine**: [JSFiddle without ngShow](http://jsfiddle.net/FF9wC/1/)

Does anyone know of a good way to use `ngShow` and focus the element being showed at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $timeout:

```
.directive('previewFocus', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.$watch('preview', 
         function (newValue) { 
            console.log('preview changed!')
            $timeout(function() {
                newValue && element[0].focus();
            }, 0, false);
         });
      };    
});
```

This works because $timeout defers execution of the code inside $timeout until after the render phase (so after the $watch for ng-show is executed, when the textarea becomes visible)

Side Note: I removed the second argument to your $watch - a deep watch is not necessary for a $watch on a primitive variable.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jj2zd/)

Comment: I re-thought this. Since you haven't modified any $scope variables, another $digest does not need to be triggered. Updated Post to pass 'false' as the third argument to $timeout so that $apply is not called.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack, but does the job ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dm5LG/2/)):

```
function (newValue) { 
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    newValue && element[0].focus();
  }, 0);
},true);
```

Of course in this case, Angular's $timeout would be preferred.